# Spinner listener OnItemSelectedListener function without click on spinner

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

I have an activity Advanced Research, with a spinner that contains all category from my db. When i create the activity, this spinner call onSetItemListener in loop. Why?

I try to use onTouchListener but not working, maybe i fail something.

```
if(risultato.getCategoria().getSottocategorie().toArray() != null && risultato.getCategoria().getSottocategorie().toArray().length != 0){
                adapterSpinnerCategoria = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, risultato.getCategoria().getSottocategorie().toArray());
            }else{
                adapterSpinnerCategoria = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, categoriaVuota);
            }
            spinnerCategoria.setAdapter(adapterSpinnerCategoria);



 public void spinnerChange(AdapterView<?> parent){
        if(!parent.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Sottocategorie vuote")) {
            ricercaAvanzata.setCategoria((Categoria) parent.getSelectedItem());
            setArticoli();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        spinnerChange(parent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        return;
    }



 public void setListener() {
        spinnerCategoria.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    }


public class ActivityRicercaAvanzata extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener { .... }
```

I expect that when i click on spinner call onItemSelected not before

Answer (score 1):

i am using Spinner for Country Selection for User Registration.
   please vote my answer.

```
Spinner spcountry;
String  country;

//in onCreare
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

spcountry = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.country);
        final String[] countryNames = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.countries_array);
        ArrayAdapter aa = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, countryNames);
        aa.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        //Setting the ArrayAdapter data on the Spinner
        spcountry.setAdapter(aa);


spcountry.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Log.v("item", (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
                if (position == 0) {

                    return;
                } else
                    country = countryNames[position];
                //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),country,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: Not working :( When i call my method for update a filters, this go in loop :( 
I need a method for add at Set<Model> in first position a item.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, you are **extending**  AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener.
You cannot extend it since  OnItemSelectedListener  is an interface, not a class.

What you actually should be doing is, implementing it instead, like so:

```
MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

}
```

Then you can set the OnItemSelectedListener on the Spinner,

```
spinnerCategoria.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

And the final step would be to write the implementation for the overridden methods,

```
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        //Your implementation here
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        //Your implementation here
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, i implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener but i write extends in this topic. Sorry for my mistake :( 
I do like u said but not working :(
When i create this spinner he call this action (onItemSelected) in a loop, until not found another subcategory, and he stop. 
But i must to choose for expample :
Hardware -> CPU -> INTEL -> Etc
Software -> Antivirus -> etc
But this spinner take position 0, and go in loop and when i create an activity, he show only a intel cpu because is at position 0 in spinner each time.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, mark as solved thx. I create a new List and i convert my set into list. After this operation i add a null element at first position, and when i'm call onItemSelected, i do

if(position != 0)then
    //do something

Activity start always at position 0 then must wait my click and my choice. Thx all for help me.